# How to draw a animation upon a background image in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code, I used two image, one for background image and one for the pinball animation, but with this code, the ball will wipe off the background image within it's flying trace so I need some help that can allow me draw on a transparent bufferedimage then put it as a mask over the background image. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainTest {

    private final int TABLE_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int TABLE_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final int BALL_SIZE = 16;
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Pinball game");
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int ySpeed = 5;
    private double xyRate = rand.nextDouble() - 0.5;
    private int xSpeed = (int) (ySpeed * xyRate * 2);
    private int ballX = rand.nextInt(200) + 20;
    private int ballY = rand.nextInt(10) + 20;

    private BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel();
    private Foreground foreground = new Foreground();
    private int preX = -1;
    private int preY = -1;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Image back = new ImageIcon("res/cat1.jpg").getImage();
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    Timer timer;

    public void init() {
//      Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
//      image = g.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(30, 30, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        background.setBackground(new ImageIcon("res/cat1.jpg"));
        background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT));
        foreground.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT));
        background.add(foreground);
        f.add(background);

        ActionListener taskPerformer = evt -> {
            if (ballX <= 0 || ballX >= TABLE_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE) {
                xSpeed = -xSpeed;
            }
            else if (ballY <= 0 || (ballY >= TABLE_HEIGHT - BALL_SIZE)) {
                ySpeed = -ySpeed;
            }
            ballY += ySpeed;
            ballX += xSpeed;
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
            if (preX == -1) {
                preX = ballX;
                preY = ballY;
            }
            g.clearRect(preX, preY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
            preX = ballX;
            preY = ballY;
            foreground.repaint();
        };
        timer = new Timer(10, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainTest().init();
    }

    public class Foreground extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Foreground() {
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(back, 0, 0, this);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}


public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6702278957072713279L;
    private Icon wallpaper;

    public BackgroundPanel() {
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (null != wallpaper) {
            processBackground(g);
        }
    }

    public void setBackground(Icon wallpaper) {
        this.wallpaper = wallpaper;
        this.repaint();
    }

    private void processBackground(Graphics g) {
        ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) wallpaper;
        Image image = icon.getImage();
        int cw = getWidth();
        int ch = getHeight();
        int iw = image.getWidth(this);
        int ih = image.getHeight(this);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (y <= ch) {
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
            x += iw;
            if (x >= cw) {
                x = 0;
                y += ih;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to for a better understanding of how the painting process and how you're suppose to work with it. Before you get worried about optimisation, focus on just making it work as simply as you can

Comment: That doesn't help alot on my question, could you advise when I add 2 Jpanels to one JFrame, which one is the best practice, JFrame.add(JPanel1) then JFrame.add(JPanel2)? or JPanes1.add(JPanel2) then JFrame.add(JPanel1)? I tried both and set the foreground JPanel.setOpaque(false), but my problem didn't be solved.

Comment: Neither, because it’s not really how you should be going it, as I said, understand how the api works first, the change your design to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw ball after draw background image.

in your case, draw ball after method "processBackground".

Comment: Thanks the problem fixed, So I don't need use two JPanels for this scenario right? Just use one JPanel and draw a background image then draw other shapes after that. Thanks alot.

Comment: Yes! right. and please accept my answer. i want get privilege.

Answer (score -1):

I got this problem solved, and post the code here, thanks @MadProgrammer and @SuperShark's help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainTest {

    private final int TABLE_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int TABLE_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final int BALL_SIZE = 16;
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Pinball game");
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int ySpeed = 5;
    private double xyRate = rand.nextDouble() - 0.5;
    private int xSpeed = (int) (ySpeed * xyRate * 2);
    private int ballX = rand.nextInt(200) + 20;
    private int ballY = rand.nextInt(10) + 20;

    private BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel();   
    Timer timer;

    public void init() {

        background.setBackground(new ImageIcon("res/cat1.jpg"));
        background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT));

        f.add(background);

        ActionListener taskPerformer = evt -> {
            if (ballX <= 0 || ballX >= TABLE_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE) {
                xSpeed = -xSpeed;
            } else if (ballY <= 0 || (ballY >= TABLE_HEIGHT - BALL_SIZE)) {
                ySpeed = -ySpeed;
            }
            ballY += ySpeed;
            ballX += xSpeed;
            background.repaint();
        };
        timer = new Timer(10, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainTest().init();
    }

    public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6702278957072713279L;
        private Icon wallpaper;

        public BackgroundPanel() {
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (null != wallpaper) {
                processBackground(g);
                drawball(g);
            }
            System.out.println("f:paintComponent(Graphics g)");
        }

        public void setBackground(Icon wallpaper) {
            this.wallpaper = wallpaper;
            this.repaint();
        }

        private void processBackground(Graphics g) {
            ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) wallpaper;
            Image image = icon.getImage();
            int cw = getWidth();
            int ch = getHeight();
            int iw = image.getWidth(this);
            int ih = image.getHeight(this);
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            while (y <= ch) {
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
                x += iw;
                if (x >= cw) {
                    x = 0;
                    y += ih;
                }
            }
        }
        private void drawball(Graphics g){
             g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
             g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```